# moving a node from different arrays to one array and again moving it to parent array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[![enter image description here][1]][1]in angularjs i have different arrays named as list1 ,list2,list3 each array is used in different list .I have two buttons and two div left div showing different array elements right div showing element from right div so when i click on the element on left div and pressed right button then the element should removed from left and inserted to right div.and when i pressed element on right div and left button the element should be removed from right div and should be inserted to the left div and parent array which i have removed earlier from that parent array

html code is :

```
      <p ng-repeat="item in list1" id="attr">{{item}}</p>
       <button id="btn-right" ng-click="add()">rig</button>
        <button id="btn-left">left</button>
```

angular code is:

```
   $scope.list = ['date', 'birth'];
    $scope.list1 = ['date', 'birth'];
    $scope.list2 = ['date', 'birth'];
    $scope.select=[];


   $scope.insert=function(item,list){
       attribute= item;
     $scope. naml=list;
       console.log(naml);

     };
     $scope.add=function()
     {
        var index=$scope.naml.indexOf(attribute);
        $scope.naml.splice(index, 1); 
        $scope.select.push(attribute);
        attribute=null;
        }
```

Comment: can you please add a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: i have developed it in sublime !

Comment: Actually i cann't understand your question. Please describe it clearly.

Comment: I have two div one is on left side one is one right side and i have two buttons in between them namely rtl and ltr rtl(right to left) and ltr(left to right)on left div i have different lists shown using different arrays when i clicked on any element  on left div and ltr button the element should be displayed on right div and it should be removed from left div when i click on element on right div and rtl button it should removed from right div and should be added to same parent array which it is there before and should be displayed on left div.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this

HTML Page:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .red {
            color: red;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div style="float:left;border: solid;width: 48%;" align="center">
    <p ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-click="insert(item,'left'); 
toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">{{item}}</p>
</div>

<div style="float:right;border: solid; width: 48%;" align="center">
    <p ng-repeat="item in list2" ng-click="insert(item, 'right'); 
toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">{{item}}</p>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <button id="btn-right" ng-click="takeRight()">Right</button>
    <button id="btn-left" ng-click="takeLeft()">Left</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.list1 = ['dateleft', 'birth'];
$scope.list2 = ['dateright', 'death'];
$scope.itemsOnLeft=[];
$scope.itemsOnRight=[];

$scope.insert=function(item, to){
    switch(to) {
        case "left":
            var index = $scope.itemsOnLeft.indexOf(item);
            if ( index != -1)   {
                $scope.itemsOnLeft.splice(index, 1);
            }   
            else {
                $scope.itemsOnLeft.push(item);
            }

            break;
        case "right":
            var index = $scope.itemsOnRight.indexOf(item);
            if ( index != -1)   {
                $scope.itemsOnRight.splice(index, 1);
            }   
            else {
                $scope.itemsOnRight.push(item);
            }                   
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Error in inserting");
    }
    };

    $scope.takeRight=function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsOnLeft.length; i++) {
            var item = $scope.itemsOnLeft[i];
            var index = $scope.list1.indexOf(item);
            $scope.list1.splice(index, 1); 
            $scope.list2.push(item); 
        }
        $scope.itemsOnLeft.length = 0;              
    };

    $scope.takeLeft=function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsOnRight.length; i++) {
            var item = $scope.itemsOnRight[i];
            var index = $scope.list2.indexOf(item);
            $scope.list2.splice(index, 1); 
            $scope.list1.push(item); 
        }
        $scope.itemsOnRight.length = 0;
    };
```

Note: Since you are using ng-Repeat for displaying two lists, it wont allow you add any duplicates in a list. So if you try to move some items and destination has already that item then you will end up with error.

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: can you add plunker or jsfiddle to this!

Comment: Now what if I'll say, "i have developed it in sublime !"   :D

Comment: i want to add js fiddle but i have no time i have to complete that as fast i can

Comment: In this solution you can even select multiple items at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("stack", [])
    .controller("move", function($scope) {
        // this.apps = features;
        $scope.leftList = [1, 2, 3];
        $scope.rightList = [4, 5, 6];
        var left, right;
        $scope.getLeft = function(item) {
            left = item;
        }
        $scope.getRight = function(item) {
            right = item;
        }
        $scope.ltr = function() {
            console.log("left ", left);
            if ($scope.leftList.length) {
                $scope.leftList.forEach(function(each, index) {
                    if (each === left) {
                        $scope.leftList.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
                $scope.rightList.push(left);
                left = "";
            }
        }
        $scope.rtl = function() {
            console.log("right ", right);
            if ($scope.rightList.length) {
                $scope.rightList.forEach(function(each, index) {
                    if (each === right) {
                        $scope.rightList.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
                $scope.leftList.push(right);
                right = "";
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
.left,
.right {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.butltr,
.butrtl {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="move">
    <div class="left">
        <div ng-repeat="item in leftList track by $index" ng-click="getLeft(item)">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <button class="butltr" ng-click="ltr()">ltr</button>
    <button class="butrtl" ng-click="rtl()">rtl</button>
    <div class="right">
        <div ng-repeat="item in rightList track by $index" ng-click="getRight(item)">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have added a basic design.please check it and let me know.